# How to find specific roles in many-to-many spring relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have following entities

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class Role extends AbstractEntity {

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "privilege_roles",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id")})
  @Exclude
  private Set<Privilege> privileges;

  @ManyToMany(
      cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType},
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "user_roles",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
  private Set<User> users;
}

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class Privilege extends AbstractEntity {

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "privilege_roles",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
  private Set<Role> roles;
}

/** Model użytkownika */
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

  private String login;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "user_roles",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
 
  private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Abstract entity consist of ID's and so on. My problem is to get priviliges from a specific user, can it be done with one query? At this point, I've divided it down into two steps

```
  Set<Role> findByUsers_Login(String login);
```

```
  Set<Privilege> getAllByRolesIdIn(Collection<@Nonnull Integer> roles_id);
```

How can I achieve my goal, if notice anything related to clean-code or a performance improvement, I would be grateful

```
HashSet<PrivilegeDto> authorities = new HashSet<>();
UserDto userDto = userService.findByLogin(login)
Set<Long> rolesId = roleService(findByUserId(userDto.getId().stream()
        .map(AbstractDto::getId)
        .collect(Collectors::toSet());
for (Long id : rolesId) {
    Set<PrivilegeDto> privilegesById = privilegeService.getPrivilegesById(id);
    authorities.addAll(privilegesById);
}
```

```
@Query(value = "SELECT P.NAME FROM USER_ROLES UR LEFT JOIN PRIVILEGE_ROLES PR ON PR.ROLE_ID = UR.ROLE_ID LEFT JOIN PRIVILEGE P ON PR.PRIVILEGE_ID = P.ID LEFT JOIN USER U ON U.ID = UR.USER_ID WHERE U.LOGIN = :login",nativeQuery = true)
    Set<Privilege> getAllMyPriviliges(@Param("login")String login);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a hard time understanding why you need the second query. With the first one, you would get a set of `Role`s. The `Role` object already contains a set of `Privilege`s which you can simply retrieve using the getter method as follows:

```java
findByUsers_Login(login).stream()
    .flatMap(role -> role.getPrivileges().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I need a second query because my DTO returned from Role doesn't contain a Set. Mapping the first query shows Set <Set <Roles>>

Comment: Then you need to add more code to your question so that we can help you. How do you get the `Set<Role>` from the repository?

Comment: Sure thing, right now see last snippets

Comment: In my opinion that is the issue of following the rule of pass-around DTOs within the Service layer instead of entities themselves. Nevertheless, why don't your `UserDto` include `Set<RoleDto>` that would include `Set<PrivilegeDto>`? With that you simplify your code and avoid duplicate, unnecessary and avoidable trips to the database.

Comment: Yeah, I also think about rearrange DTOs but to be honest it wasn't my case. I focused on accessing priviliges by writing a good query.

Comment: So I assume you are only interested in the user Privileges and nothing else from the User object. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's it

Comment: I created something like this, but it doesn't work

Comment: Then, assuming you have a `JpaRepository` for `Privilege`, you can try adding the following method `findAllByRolesUsersLogin(String login)`, that Spring Data will read and build the corresponding query.

Comment: That was really helpfull, yesterday i tried almost the same but without 's' in Users. Thank You @João Dias

Comment: Is your issue solved now? If it is and my answer helped you consider upvoting it and even accept it as the answer so that others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!